# WIX MSI package

Tags: wix

I am new to WIX and trying to create a WIX for my Web application.

I have run `heat.exe` as PreBuild Event of Installer setup project.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin\heat.exe" dir "$(Wixdest)" -cg BUDirect -gg -scom -sreg -sfrag -srd -dr INSTALLLOCATION -var env.Wixdest -out "C:\Workspaces\Chatra\BUFragment.wxs"
```

The `BUfragment.wxs` is created as specified above and reference structure of all `dll,xml,pdb` is seen in `BUfragment.wxs`  after compile; and `CAB` and `MSI` package is created in `Bin\Release` folder.

But when i try to see into Cab non of the files related to Web application or `TARGETDIR` are not their.

What could have been gone wrong and any idea if am I missing some configuration settings?

Comment: In your WIX project `<Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes"/>` this line should embed all the files into your msi package. Are you sure your are referencing the components from the generated wxs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you added the `<ComponentGroupRef Id="BUDirect" />` created in the BUFragment.wxs into a feature?

Fragments are only included within the build when you reference one of the elements within the  fragment.